# автоматическая прокрутка в QScrollArea

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

В QScrollArea добавляются объекты.
как автоматически заставить прокручиваться QScrollArea , чтобы увидеть добавленные объекты?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После добавление вы можете делать скролл по абсолютной позиции:

[QScrollArea::ensureVisible(int x, int y, int xmargin = 50, int ymargin = 50)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#ensureWidgetVisible)

или (в вашем конкретном случае это удобнее), скроллить до видимости виджета

[QScrollArea::ensureWidgetVisible(QWidget *childWidget, int xmargin = 50, int ymargin = 50)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#ensureWidgetVisible)

Comment: благодарю Вас и рву волосы на своей голове из-за невнимательного чтения документации